# Overload method depending on calling instance

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I really new at programming, thus always thinking that i could do cleaner and more simple code.

I want to know, is there a way to implement different behaviour of method, depending on instance where it was called?

***E.g:***

```
param = worker.CreateWindow(elemParams);
```

is called from `LevelCommand`

```
param = worker.CreateWindow(elemParams);
```

is called from `IntersectionCommand`

`CreateWindow` calls constructor for WPF model, which have ***TextBox*** (ofc there are more items, but only textbox is relevant), and depending on command, it need to display different strings.("choose param for `{callerclass}`).

Here is the  constructor:

```
public Model(List<string> attribute, string caller)
{
    try
    {
        if (attribute.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("Нет подходящих параметров");
        Attd = attribute;
        Attw = attribute;
        Caption = "Выберите параметр для \nзаписи "+caller; //Bound to the TextBox, point of my question
        Vis = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TaskDialog.Show("Title", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

As you can see, so far i tried just to pass a constant string, which i do not consider a great solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the CallerMemberName attributer:

```
public Model(List<string> attribute, [CallerMemberName] string caller="")
```

[Link to MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netframework-4.8)